# How to communicate with Pi with an invalid IP address?

Tags: networking, home-automation

I am building a home automation solution based on the RPi. Since the Pi will be using my home WiFi, it will inevitably have an invalid IP address (one that will be mapped to a valid IP by my WiFi modem). I plan to build an iphone app that will let me communicate with the RPi and monitor different parameters and change settings. 
I am wondering how I can communicate with the RPi over the internet, considering that it will have an invalid IP address. The Nest thermostats must be facing the same problem. How would Nest keep track of their thermostats inside homes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP address on a home network wont be *invalid*. Your home router allocates dynamic internal IP addresses to devices on your network, these are not accessible from outside.

However, you can tell your router to create a link between the outside world and a device on your internal network. This is called *port forwarding*. Essentially you tell the router which IP address on your home network you want to communicate with by specifying a port on the external IP.

There is a resource [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/) that explains the process in more detail.

One caveat is that your ISP may assign your router a dynamic IP address itself, which may change every day, week, month, each time the router is turned on, or at any other random time. There's not a whole lot you can do about this. Some ISPs allow you to specify a fixed IP address that doesn't change, or some offer the service at an extra fee.

In summary, you can communicate with your Pi from outside your home network, but you **will need to forward the ports on your router, and it will be easier with a fixed IP from your ISP**.

Comment: @EhsanShams No problem! Glad I could help